# How to do the Azure SSO in a POST request PHP?

Tags: php, azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, single-sign-on

I could do the SSO in browser successfully. But my new requirement is to do the SSO in a POST method on our side to for to use another website. May I know how is it possible ?

The following link is the usual URL we use to do the SSO,

*https://login.microsoftonline.com/your tenant id/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?state=session_id()&scope=profile+openid+email&response_type=code&approval_prompt=auto&client_id=your client id&redirect_uri=your redirect uri*

Here is my process,

Website B call a POST request to W

- Website A call a POST request to Website B
- Website B need to do the SSO
- In SSO, if user not logged in then the SSO will ask for sign in
- After successful sign in we get the user details from the authorization
- Return the result to Website A

Comment: Is Website A's backend code supposed to access website B using the identity of a human user, or as an application? The Oauth flows are different in each case. MS documentation explains this, I believe.

Comment: @ADyson Website B is only for the identity of verification using SSO. 

If it is a valid user I sent a api request to Website A to allow the user to using website